# Semi-automatic image thresholding with python and skimage

Tags: python, scikit-image, imagej

I am looking for a solution to semi-automatic thresholding in Python. Does skimage or similar package have a prebuilt grayscale threshold range for selection? I've included imageJ threshold which I would like to reproduce. [image]

Comment: Python and skimage gives are only tools to write code and you have to write GUI on your own. `cv2` can display image in window and it can add some buttons to this window which you could use to select options but still it needs to write some code. Or you can use `Jupyter Notebook` to run code using web browser to display images and add some widgets in web browser - buttons, sliders, dropdown menu, etc..

Comment: In addition to @furas comment: OpenCV has some trackbar functionality, see [this example](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/da/d6a/tutorial_trackbar.html). Using trackbars, you could replicate half of the above functionality. Do you want to fully reproduce the ImageJ tool - or what do you specifically need? If you add some code attempts, people will gladly help to improve your approaches.

Comment: I was searching example with `buttons` but I found [example in Python](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_trackbar/py_trackbar.html#code-demo) which `trackbars`. For something more you may need to use GUI frameworks `tkinter`, `PyQt`, `PyGTK`, `wxPython`. You may also use mouse events and text on image to simulate buttons like `record` in this [example](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/cv2/display-button)

Comment: Do you maybe mean you want scikit-image to suggest a threshold? Have a look at Otsu https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_thresholding.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-segmentation-plot-thresholding-py

Comment: @MarkSetchell thanks, that module looks like it is as good alternative. It be nice to make the gui as described by, maybe when I have a little more time.